# System overlay или как отрисовать кастомную мышку поверх всего?

Tags: android, gui

Добрый день.

Появилась надобность отрисовать кастомную мышку. Первым делом, конечно, загуглил на наличие подобных приложений и не нашел ничего кроме [Tap Pointer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jkhddev.mouemu&hl=ru), который требует рут и при этом работает просто ужасно (по крайней мере на моём Nexus 5 с Android 7.1).

После этого решил сделать собственное приложение, но т.к. я новичок в программировании под Android, сразу возникли некоторые вопросы.
С помощью [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top) и [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516089/draw-over-navigation-bar-and-other-apps-on-android-version-5) смог добиться рисования поверх почти всех окон. Но так и не удалось добиться рисования поверх навигации. Вычитал, что начиная с API 23 с этим есть проблемы, но я знаю, что есть способы это сделать т.к. есть приложение [Twilight](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.urbandroid.lux&hl=ru), которое покрывает красным фильтром весь экран, включая навигацию.

Кроме того, мне никак не удаётся сделать кликабельную кнопку в оверлее. События касаний и нажатий просто не отлавливаются.

**Код, который у меня получился:**

```
public class MousePointerService extends Service {
    private WindowManager wm;

    private PointerView pointerArea;
    private Button overlayButton;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        pointerArea = new PointerView(this);
        pointerArea.setBackgroundColor(0x33aaddff); // Заполнить всю область полупрозрачным голубым, чтобы понять где можно рисовать
        WindowManager.LayoutParams pointerAreaParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        wm.addView(pointerArea, pointerAreaParams);

        overlayButton = new Button(this);
        overlayButton.setText("Test");
        overlayButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        overlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Это событие никогда не вызывается
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"onClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        overlayButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // И это событие тоже почему-то никогда не вызывается
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"onTouch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        wm.addView(overlayButton, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"onDestroy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (overlayButton != null) {
            wm.removeView(overlayButton);
            overlayButton = null;
        }

        if(pointerArea != null) {
            wm.removeView(pointerArea);
            pointerArea = null;
        }
    }
}

public class PointerView extends View {
    private Paint paint;

    PointerView(MousePointerService context) {
        super(context);

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        paint.setAlpha(127);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(60);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawPoint(100, 100, paint); // Пробуем отрисовать что-нибудь в кастомном View
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Это событие никогда не вызывается
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"onTouchEvent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Так же, имеется следующее разрешение:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

И в настройках приложения выданы права накладываться на все окна.

**Скриншот результата:**

[image: Результат]

Как видно, точка отрисовалась, кнопка тоже, и весь экран, за исключением полоски навигации запрашен полупрозрачным голубым. И кнопка при этом не кликабельна.

**Теперь кратко вопросы:**

1. Как отрисовать что-либо поверх навигации? Да ещё так, чтобы это
   подходило к Android 4.0+
2. Как отловить все события касания? Для того чтобы управлять кастомной мышкой отовсюду. (И можно ли это сделать без рута)
3. Как заставить кнопку чувстовать нажатия?

Знаю, что в андройде есть собственный курсор, но насчет него не смог найти ничего полезного, а из того, что нашел у меня сложилось впечатление, что с ним без рута не обойтись.

**P.S.** Возможно вопросы глупые или мою проблему можно решить гораздо проще, прошу мне на это указать, если это так.

Этот вопрос на англоязычном сайте ["System overlay. How I can draw over nav bar and how to catch touch events?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593883/system-overlay-how-i-can-draw-over-nav-bar-and-how-to-catch-touch-events)

Comment: Добавил код и скриншот работы приложения.
Так же сделал копию темы на англоязычном сайте. Если там ответят - напишу решение сюда.